# Which HTTP version does file_get_contents use by default?

Tags: php, http, file-get-contents

Recently, one of our service providers sent this update to their service:

using the `HTTP 1.0` protocol:
API calls will return `HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request` ... should update their code to `HTTP 1.1` and include the Host header in the API request.

Does PHP's [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) do all that by default?

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a stream_context to file_get_contents like the code below:

```
<?php
// Create a stream
$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n" .
              "Cookie: foo=bar\r\n"
  )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

// Open the file using the HTTP headers set above
$file = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/', false, $context);
?>
```

You can find more in the PHP manual at:
http://us.php.net/file_get_contents

Hope it helps.

Comment: How that will change _version_ of protocol used?

Comment: Check the above answers about changing the protocols.
Basically you can change the headers of the request as you require. You can also add or remove any headers. :)

Answer (score 1):

According to https://www.php.net/manual/de/context.http.php the default Context `protocol_version` is `1.0`. You should simply set it via

```
<?php
$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET"
  )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts, 
                    array ('protocol_version'=> '1.1')
);

$file = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/', false, $context);
?>
```

(see https://www.php.net/stream_context_create)

UPDATE FOR PHP 8.0

As of this version, the default `protocol_version` is `1.1` [See commit `f9f769d`](https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/f9f769d4b9af367af864d35cf09dca5b08da2046)

Comment: Replace `array ('protocol_version'=> '1.1')` by `array ('http' => array('protocol_version'=> '1.1'))`

Answer (score 0):

Use the `protocol_version` option in the `http` element of the `context` argument to `file_get_contents`. It defaults to version `1.0`. See [HTTP Context Options](http://us.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php) for more details.